Generating set of permutation group such that generators do not "contain" other group elements
Let $(G, X)$ be a permutation group with domain $X$.  Let $O=\{o_1,\dots,o_m\}$ be the set of orbits of $G$.  I am interested in generating sets $S$ with the following property:

Let $g\in S$ be a generator.  Write $g$ as $\prod_{i=1}^m g_i$ such that $g_i$ moves only points in $o_i$, that is, $g_i$ coincides with $g$ on $o_i$ and is the identity elsewhere.  Then there is no non-empty subset of non-identity elements in $\{g_1,\dots,g_m\}$ whose product is not $g$ and is in $G$.

For example, the two generating sets
\begin{align*}
&(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)(10,11),\; (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,9,8)\quad\text{and}\\
&(1,2,3)(4,5,6),\; (7,8,9),\;(10,11)
\end{align*}
generate the same group $G$, with orbits $o_1=\{1,2,3\}$, $o_2=\{4,5,6\}$, $o_3=\{7,8,9\}$ and $o_4=\{10,11\}$.  The first of the two generating sets does not have the desired property, because $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ is in $G$ (or also $(10,11)$), whereas the second does.

Does this property, or a generating set with this property, have a name?
Is there a fast way to produce such a generating set (other than testing all subsets)?


It is not obvious to me what you mean by "is a generator". I also don't guess the intended meaning of the set ${g_1\dots g_m:g_i\neq 1}$ since the $g_j$ seemed to had been fixed beforehand. (Also, is $m$, the number of orbits, the same as the $m$ in $g_1\dots g_m$?)

"is a generator" refers to the given generating set.  The set ${g_1,\dots,g_m\mid g_i\neq 1}$ is obtained by restricting $g$ to each of the orbits $o_1,\dots,o_m$ and discard identity elements.  Does this make it clearer?

I'm afraid not. "The given generating set": no generating set has been introduced. "Is obtained by" is a bit vague. Do you mean the following: "Let $g\in G$, and let $g_i$ coincide with $g$ on $o_i$ and be identity elsewhere, so that $g=\prod g_i$. Still I have no idea what is meant by ${g_1,\dots,g_m|g_i\neq 1}$, in the absence of quantifiers indicating what is fixed and what is not fixed (especially $g$, $i$), and what ranges over what.

I edited the question, is it clearer now?  (Briefly: yes, your interpretation of what the $g_i$ are is what I intended.  I rearranged the subset property in the question.  Thank you so much for helping to improve the question!

Do you have an example where such group elements exist but they don't generate the full group?  I believe that needs at least three orbits.

@BrendanMcKay, I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Could you please expand!

Chang, Mun See; Jefferson, Christopher, Disjoint direct product decompositions of permutation groups,  ZBL07379067.
solves the problem.

Don't forget to accept your own answer if it resolves the question.

this might even be already implemented in GAP

Indeed, there is an implementation: https://github.com/peal/DisjointDirectProdDecomposition

There is now an alternative implementation in upcoming sagemath 10.5.
